# How can I pass a String to name an object?

Tags: java, object, arraylist, naming

I need to create a number of objects to populate an ArrayList. These objects need to be uniquely identified. I was hoping to let the user name the objects. When I go to pass the reference variable of the String to name the object, it is not allowed.

```
String input;
Object { input } = new Object();
arrayList.addObject( { input } );
```

If there is no way to dynamically name objects, how might I go about creating these objects?

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand exactly what you want, but would a `Map` of some kind meet your needs, such as a `HashMap<String,Object>` ?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Is there any way to give an object a name input by the user without using a map?

Comment: Why don't you want to use a map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object` doesn't have a `name` field. You could create your own class and then add an instance of that class to your collection.

You could do this:

```
public class CustomItem
{
        private String name;

        public CustomItem(String n)
        {
            this.name = n;
        }

        public String getName()
        {
            return this.name;
        }
}
```

And add it to your `arrayList` like this:

`arrayList.add(new CustomItem("I1"));`

If you wanted to check if a particular element of the collection matched some name, you would call the `getName()` method on that element and compare it some name.

Comment: The way you added the item to the arrayList is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're not trying to name an *object*; you're trying to name a *variable*. The solution is: don't. That's not how Java works. In Java, variable names really don't matter all that much and are almost non-existent in compiled code. Rather *references* are what matter. Instead use a `Map<String, MyType>` to associated a String with an object. A `HashMap<String, SomeType>` would work well here.

Answer (score 0):

You likely dont want to use the `Object` class. Instead, you should make your own class (which automatically inherits from `Object` that has a `String` field called `name`. IE:

```
Class MyClass{
    myClass(String s){ name = s;}
    private String name;
}
```

Then you can do `MyClass myClass = new MyClass(name-inputted-by-user);` and add it to your array list. You will likely also want to override the `equals` function so that it compares names